# Github personal page not updating with new commits

Tags: github, github-pages

I have my personal website hosted on github `username.github.io` repo, weird thing is that after I pushed my new modifications to the repo, the page was still showing the content of my previous commit, but when I checked the content in that repo on github, it is the latest. Any idea what might be wrong. Some say it take a little while for the new content to show, but now it is almost 1 hour past.

Comment: Did you add it to the `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. I pushed everything under master.

Comment: @Blake You don't need to use the `gh-pages` branch for `username.github.io` repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the problem, it was due to one module failed build in my project, after fixing that it works successfully.

Comment: Which module was failing to build?